# How to train NLP classification using keras library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, keras, training-data

Here is my training data, I want to predict 'y' with X_data using keras library. I am getting an error for a lot of time, I know its about the data shape but I am stuck for a some time. Hope you guys could help.

```
X_data =
0     [construction, materials, labour, charges, con...
1     [catering, catering, lunch]
2     [passenger, transport, local, transport, passe...
3     [goods, transport, road, transport, goods, inl...
4     [rental, rental, aircrafts]
5     [supporting, transport, cargo, handling, agenc...
6     [postal, courier, postal, courier, local, deli...
7     [electricity, charges, reimbursement, electric...
8     [facility, management, facility, management, p...
9     [leasing, leasing, aircrafts]
10    [professional, technical, business, selling, s...
11    [telecommunications, broadcasting, information...
12    [support, personnel, search, contract, tempora...
13    [maintenance, repair, installation, maintenanc...
14    [manufacturing, physical, inputs, owned, other...
15    [accommodation, hotel, accommodation, hotel, i...
16    [leasing, rental, leasing, renting, motor, veh...
17    [real, estate, rental, leasing, involving, pro...
18    [rental, transport, vehicles, rental, road, ve...
19    [cleaning, sanitary, pad, vending, machine]
20    [royalty, transfer, use, ip, intellectual, pro...
21    [legal, accounting, legal, accounting, legal, ...
22    [veterinary, clinic, health, care, relation, a...
23    [human, health, social, care, inpatient, medic...
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

​And here is my training predictor

```
y = 

0      1
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      1
6      1
7      1
8      1
9      1
10     1
11     1
12     1
13     1
14     1
15    10
16     2
17    10
18     2
19     2
20    10
21    10
22    10
23    10
```

I am using this model:

```
top_words = 5000
length= len(X_data)
embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(embedding_vecor_length, top_words, input_length=length))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_data, y, epochs=3, batch_size=32)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_8_input to have shape (None, 24) but got array with shape (24, 1)
```

What is the problem with using this data in this model? I want to predict 'y' using input X_data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your pandas dataframes to numpy arrays, the arrays are going to be ragged so you need to pad them. You also need to setup a dictionary of word vectors, as you cannot just pass words directly into a neural network. Some examples are, [here](https://gist.github.com/entron/b9bc61a74e7cadeb1fec),[here](http://www.orbifold.net/default/2017/01/10/embedding-and-tokenizer-in-keras/), and [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/). Your're going to need to do your own research here, Its not possible to do much with the data sample you provided

`length = len(X_data)` is how many samples of data you have, keras doesn't care about this, it wants to know how many words you have as an input, (has to be the same for each, which is why padding was stated earlier)

so your input to the network is how many columns you have

```
#assuming you converted X_data correctly to numpy arrays and word vectors
model.add(Embedding(embedding_vecor_length, top_words, input_length=X_data.shape[1]))
```

Your categorical values need to be binary.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

y = to_categorical(y)
```

Your last dense layer is now 10, assuming that you have 10 categories and the correct activation is `softmax` for a mulitclass problem

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

your loss now has to be `categorical_crossentropy`, since this is multiclass

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I got it working! but I can't predict anything again it shows some shape error. It's really frustrating, to be honest. Can you tell what kind of data will it take to get the right prediction?

Comment: I cannot without knowing the error, or exactly what the new setup you used is. So your saying the model trains but when you run `model.predict()` you get some error?

Comment: I sort of got the predict by following the padding and encoding step for the text but the output seems wierd

For the input : jelly = 'service charges. consultancy services for june'

i get output :
array([[ 0.48915482],
       [ 0.48839182],
       [ 0.49011096],
       [ 0.48880994],
       [ 0.4904303 ],
       [ 0.48839182],
       [ 0.48839182],
....

This pattern is similar for every input near 0.48-0.495 for all inputs i tried

Comment: I personally don't believe I can debug this problem in the comments, as I'm already confused by the output, and there will be an additional 15 or so comments to really know the problem. I would suggest, you give the debugging a shot (we learn best through a bit of struggle), and then ask a new question if it becomes too much, as this is already becoming a separate question